# match only once but not more

Tags: regex, perl

I want to check existence of server name taken from one file in another one. The idea is that second file holds multiple lines with server name + additional info in each.

so the output for the example name "server01" is

```
server01
server01
server01
```

i want to have it only once in output xls file for each name that exist in both files of course.

The program so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w


use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

#OPEN FILES
open(FILE, "CEP06032012.csv") or die("Unable to open CEP file");
@CEP_file = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

open(FILE, "listsystems_temp") or die("Unable to open listsystems file");
@listsystems_file = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

#XLS properties
my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('report.xls');
my $worksheet_servers = $workbook->add_worksheet();


#MAIN
my $r = 0;
foreach my $lines(@CEP_file){ 

my @CEP_file = split ";", $lines;
my $server = $CEP_file[8];

foreach my $lines2(@listsystems_file){

    if ($lines2 =~ m/.*$server.*/i && $server ne ""){
        print "$server \n";
        #print "$lines2 \n";
        $worksheet_servers->write($r, 0, "$server");
        $r++;
    }
} 

}


exit();
```

any ideas how to change it?

Comment: How to remove duplicates is in one of the perlfaq pages.

Comment: these ale not exactly duplicates as for example the second file contains:
    `F_server01:NO - v1`
    `F_server01:LZ - v2`
so the part of the each line could be same but not all line...

Comment: you are currently showing exact duplicates being outputted, and you asked how to prevent that. Are you changing your question? If so, what's your new question?

Comment: in my comment I showed two example lines in file listsystems_temp, if we take "server01" name from CEP file and parse listystems_temp we get the situation i showed in main question, and I want to prevent that. To be honest I didn't found any useful for me info in faq... and in comment I want to tell more details because I think u have misunderstood me. sorry for confusion

Comment: perlfaq4 shows how to remove teh duplicates if they're in anm array. So instead of printing them, put them in an array. After the loop is done, remove the duplicates, and do whatever it is you want to do with the unique values.  Or use the last method presented !$seen{$_}++ if you want to avoid all of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will skip multiple occurance of $server, keep only one.

```
my %seen;

foreach my $lines2(@listsystems_file){
    next if $seen{$server}; 
    if ($lines2 =~ m/.*$server.*/i && $server ne ""){
        print "$server \n";
        #print "$lines2 \n";
        $worksheet_servers->write($r, 0, "$server");
        $r++;
        $seen{$server} = 1;
    }
}
```